# Add custom text to each product in cart - Magento 1.9X

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

how can I attach a custom text to a product which will be added into the cart along with the product itself when adding it to cart and furthermore being passed through the whole order process like in order page in back office or on pdf invoices and so on??

Ex :

1. When customer is on my product page he has the opportunity to
   "customize" the product with the help of a configuration wizard I
   have built with javascript/jquery.
2. List item At the end of this process customer can add customized
   product to cart which now has a custom price and a custom
   "order text" for me as the shop-owner to get all the customization
   information
3. When clicking on add-to-cart-button
   product is added to cart with new custom price and custom text

Please note that my custom text is not entered by customer. Instead it's gonna be generated by programmatically.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

1- make a text or textarea in custom options according to your need.
2- hide it by title
3- put your calculated information into that text field or text area using client side script before adding product into cart.
4- then you will be able to get that information in cart order overview and order details in frontend/backend.

Comment: Just a run down of steps with no actual information on how to accomplish each step.